# Kafka retention policy on active consumer group

Tags: apache-kafka

Does the Kafka clean up the logs only when no consumer is active on a consumer group?

When there is a lag in a partition with an active consumer, I expected the current offset (lag) to also adjust once the time set on the retention policy has passed, but it looks like the lags are still consumable after the retention period had passed as long as the consumer is attached to the group.

I tested with the log.retention.check.interval.ms set to 1ms and log.cleanup.policy to 'delete', along with the topic's retentions.ms set to 1000ms, but the lags were still consumable way past the 1000ms.
When I remove the consumer and add a consumer again to the existing group, the offset gets adjusted as expected.

Does Kafka only adjust the offset when there is no active consumer?
If so, is there a way to update the current offset according to the retention policy other than removing and recreating the consumer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's an active consumer that's committing offsets back to Kafka `__consumer_offsets` topic, then no, offset information wouldn't ever be removed, despite the original topic segments being removed to where those offsets may no longer exist. As the docs indicate, the group needs to first be inactive, but also need to **remain inactive** for several minutes.

> `offsets.retention.minutes`
> After a consumer group **loses all its consumers (i.e. becomes empty)**  its offsets will be **kept for this retention period** before getting discarded

(emphasis added)

You can call seekToEarliest / seekToEnd function if you want to always guarantee your group position rather than rely on stored offsets

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm just a little confused about the original topic segments being removed to where those offsets no longer exist. Would that mean that the messages at those offsets will no longer be actually consumable from the active consumer?

Comment: If a segment is removed, then yes, a consumer can no longer read it

Comment: But it looked like they were still readable without any error after the retention period. Are there other conditions for topic segments to be removed in addition to the `retention.ms` and `log.retention.check.interval.ms` settings?

Comment: Are you sure the segments were actually closed? Segment size matters as well